# Как организовать классы?

Tags: android, java, классы

Есть класс Catalog, он абстрактный. От него наследуются классы: Contractor, Worker, Tovar и т.д. (их много)

У каждого классы должен быть метод: `String getStrCreatTable()`. Этот метод возвращает для каждого класса строку запроса, создания таблицы базы данных. Потом хочется поместить все классы в ArrayList пробежать по всем и создать таблицы.

Опыта мало, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 7):

```
ArrayList<Catalog> items = new ArrayList<Catalog>();
items.add(new Contractor());
items.add(new Worker()); 
и т.д.
for(Catalog item : items)
{
    String sql = item.getStrCreatTable();
    //выполнить sql
}
```

без экземпляров классов

```
List<Class> classes = new ArrayList<Class>();
classes.add(Contractor.class);
classes.add(Worker.class);
for(Class clazz : classes)
{
    Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("getStrCreatTable", new Class[]{});
    String sql = (String) method.invoke(null);
    //выполнить sql
}
```

Comment: Не хочу создавать экземпляры класса Contractor и Worcer
getStrCreateTable(). Как бы сделать статистическими?

Comment: Перефразирую.

Как бы сделать getStrCreateTable() статистическим.

Comment: обновил ответ